# Show this function is not cauchy in the metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let X be the set of all continuous real valued functions on [0,1]. Let $\{f_n\} = \{t^n\}$ be a sequence in X. Let $d_1(f,g) = \displaystyle{\max_{t \; \in [0,1]}}{\; |f(t)- g(t)|}$.

i) Show that $\{f_n\}$ is not convergent in the metric space (X,$d_1$).

ii) Show that $\{f_n\}$ is not Cauchy in the metric space (X,$d_1$).

My idea for convergence is to assume that $\{f_n\}$ does converge and then reach a contradiction but I do not understand how to start that. I managed to prove that $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to $0$ on (X,$d_1$) if that helps. Once I have that $\{f_n\}$ is not convergent, does ii) follow as a direct consequence from that?

Comment: I don't know if you have these theorems, but continuous functions on compact Hausdorff topological spaces (the metric space $[0, 1]$ being one of them) are always complete, so (i) is equivalent to (ii). Also, the uniform limit of functions is always the pointwise limit. If you can show the pointwise limit is discontinuous, then the uniform limit cannot exist (as it does not belong in the space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ii). Assume that it were, then for some $N$, $|t^{n}-t^{m}|<1/2$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $n\geq m\geq N$. For $t\in[0,1)$, and taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, one has $|t^{N}|<1/2$ for all such $t$, now taking $t\rightarrow 1^{-}$ to get a contradiction.

Note that ii) implies i).

Answer (score 0):

ii follows from I since $(X,d_1)$ is  (known to be) *complete*...

For the argument see  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space...